# How do I find which JavaScript is changing an element's style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging, firebug

I have an element that's getting styles applied via JavaScript. I'm not sure exactly where; is there a way to check Firebug to show where the "element.style" is actually coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOM attribute change debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253786/dom-attribute-change-debugging)

Answer (score 26):

If you're sure it's being set on the inline `style` and not as a consequence of a stylesheet rule, you can detect changes using the non-standard Mozilla [watch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Object/watch) method:

```
document.body.style.watch('color', function(name, v0, v1) {
    alert(name+': '+v0+'->'+v1);
});
document.body.style.color= 'red';
```

You can put `debugger;` in the watcher function and look up the call stack in Firebug to see where the change was triggered.

Comment: Can someone please tell us what we do/where we put the above code?

Comment: @user1794295 in jQuery's $(document).ready(function() { /* your code goes here */ }); or something similar

Comment: Removed as of FF 58.

Answer (score 24):

On request from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094744/how-to-determine-which-javascript-class-sets-an-inline-style/15094821#15094821):

> If you have firefox you can check the "Break on Attribute Change" option in the HTML tab. Just right click the target element and the menu will pop up. After that, resize the window and it will break in the script line where the attribute is changed.
>   [image: use firebug]

Comment: I can't see the "Break On Attribute Change" option.

Comment: That menu is completely different in current FireFox, and doesn't have any of the "Break On" actions.

Answer (score 19):

You can also right click on the element in the HTML panel before the style is set and select break on Attribute Change.  Script panel must be enabled.

Comment: I can't see the "Break On Attribute Change" option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what is default tool for the job, although it has limited debugging capabilities: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Also, make sure Ad Blocker is not responsible.

Comment: Yes, pause Ad Blocker, if style getting changed to display: 'none'. Issue I had was img was not showing and the filename/url contained 'advert'.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the script view and search for ".style" in the searchbox.

Comment: That will only work in a very limited number of cases -- especially with jQuery in use.

Comment: @Brock Adams: That's true, but one can also search for `.css` ;)