# how to determine which javascript class sets an inline style

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new on a project which has a boatload of javascript classes (16-20 files) and many dynamic features. There an element which has its height and maximum height set inline from a javascript file. Is there a way to which file this is set from?

```
<div class="ccass" style="width: 100%; height: 67px; max-height: 67px;">
```

resizes to

```
<div class="ccass" style="width: 100%; height: 307px; max-height: 307px;">
```

when the window is resized. I need to disable the resizing and set a  fixed height - for some of the pages at least.

Is there some developer tool that would assist with this?

Comment: Firebug's script section may help you out.

Comment: I usually search for a selector like `ccass` in your case and then follow it from there. Usually setting a breakpoint in Firebug and then stepping through every operation.

Comment: @Bergi: Your never head of javascript class? ...they have one at a school near me that runs on a Thursday evening :P

Comment: +1 for looking up the selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have firefox you can check the "Break on Attribute Change" option in the HTML tab. Just right click the target element and the menu will pop up. After that, resize the window and it will break in the script line where the attribute is changed.

[image: use firebug]

Comment: Could you please add this answer to [How do I find which JavaScript is changing an element's style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401298/how-do-i-find-which-javascript-is-changing-an-elements-style)? I'd upvote you there :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'break in the script line where the attribute is changed'... where can I see this script?

Comment: It will jump into the script tab in firebug automatically and show you the code line where the an attribute change is made programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

grep the js sources for *resize* or *onresize* event/method and go from there.