# Which javascript is unexpectedly changing the element's style?

Tags: javascript, html

I just started to work in an existent WordPress project in order to fix some issues, so I am firstly learning about this project. Now, I want to know exactly which javascript code is unexpectedly changing an element's style at the HTML code. Maybe some plugin... I need to find it out!

[In a similar question someone has answeared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094908/880719) that you can do that in Firefox by right clicking on the element in "HTML panel", than selecting the option "Break on Attribute Change". But I can't see this option, maybe it's an outdated feature...

So, how can I know which javascript is changing the element's style??

Comment: Are you clicking on the element in the `Elements` tab of the console, or on the element in output window?

Comment: usually F12 will open up the dev console, look for the tab that says elements to locate the HTML, and in sources find you JS and put breakpoints on them, and then under debugger you can step through them.

Comment: @TheodoreHowell If he doesn't know where it's changing, how would he know where to put the breakpoint?

Comment: @Barmar I am clicking on the element in the Firefox's `Inspector` tab

Comment: I just tried it, and indeed there's no such option. Use Chrome.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed they would know what element is changing unexpectedly, and they were running a block of code that was altering it. Between that you should be able to find where the side effect is coming from.

Comment: @TheodoreHowell The whole point of the question is that they don't know which block of code is altering it, they want the debugger to tell them.

Comment: I figured they would since they are using the plugins and I would just enable/disable to find the breaking change, and then set breakpoints in JS related to the plugin causing the unwanted changes. I totally understand your point, question was worded weirdly to myself and I did not grasp it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome, right-click on the element in the inspector document and select `Break on > attribute modifications`.

Comment: That's essentially the same as what he said he tried.

Comment: No, he said he's looking for that feature and can't find it.

Comment: If he couldn't find it using almost the same instructions in the other question, how does this help?

Comment: He was using Firefox, this answer is for Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that menu option is missing in FF.

Comment: No problem, I just installed Chrome, it works. Thanks!

Comment: From that linked question, it appears that option existed in Firebug which is no longer a product since most of the features exist in the Web Developer tools.