# how to track javascript code which dynamically adds styling (css) to elements?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-image-gallery

I am using [bootstrap image gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) to display images on my website. I have added an extra column for comments (with scrollbar) so that users may comment on photo. 
Following styling is added to each div element which translates image up/down and right/left direction.

```
<div class="slide" data-index="0" style="width: 1366px; left: 0px; 
transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);"> 
<...Modal Code ...>
```

**Probelm:**

When i click on scroll-bar to scroll, whole modal move downwards/upwards due to css transform style applied on slide ( cannot find js code from where this style is appended ).

How i can overcome this problem ??

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fwk7Lmkk/3/)

Comment: To find where it is you'll have to use your debugger in the browser dev tools. Set a break point somewhere in the image gallery or modal script

Comment: @colecms it means we have to debug all js files related to bootstrap image gallery . it will require alot of effort and time......

Comment: Not only that, then change the code. You may want to instead add a class to the elements and enforce your styles with `!important`

Comment: You might find your answer here: [DOM attribute change debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253786/dom-attribute-change-debugging)